# Reading json files in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have three data types...

1) Base data
2) data_dict_1
3) data_dict_2

Base data is very well formatted json.. 
For example:

```
{"id1":"foo", "id2":"bar" ,type:"type1"}
{"id1":"foo", "id2":"bar" ,type:"type2"}
```

data_dict_1

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 foobar
....
```

data_dict_2

```
-1 foo
-2 bar
-3 foobar
... and so on
```

Now, what I want is.. if the data is of type1

Then read id1 from data_dict_1, id2 from data_dict2 and assign that integer id..
If data is of type2.. then read id1 from data_dict_2.. id2 from data_dict1.. and assign corresponding ids..
For example:

```
{"id1":1, "id2":2 ,type:"type1"}
{"id1":-1, "id2":-2 ,type:"type2"}
```

And so on..
How do i do this in pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: what you have in the upper example is **not** valid json, the `type` key is not quoted.

Assuming Pig 0.10 and up, there's the [JsonLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#jsonloadstore) built-in, which you can pass a schema to and load it with

```
data = LOAD 'loljson' USING JsonLoader('id1:chararray,id2:chararray,type:chararray');
```

and load the dicts

```
dict_1 = LOAD 'data_dict_1' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (id:int, key:chararray);
dict_2 = LOAD 'data_dict_2' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (id:int, key:chararray);
```

Then split that based on the `type` value

```
SPLIT data INTO type1 IF type == 'type1', type2 IF type == 'type2';
```

`JOIN` them appropriately

```
type1_joined = JOIN type1 BY id1, dict_1 BY key;
type1_joined = FOREACH type1_joined GENERATE type1::id1 AS id1, type1::id2 AS id2, type1::type AS type, dict_1::id AS id;

type2_joined = JOIN type2 BY id2, dict_2 BY key;
type2_joined = FOREACH type2_joined GENERATE type2::id1 AS id1, type2::id2 AS id2, type2::type AS type, dict_2::id AS id;
```

and since the schemas are equal, `UNION` them together

```
final_data = UNION type1_joined, type2_joined;
```

this produces

```
DUMP final_data;

(foo,bar,type2,-2)
(foo,bar,type1,1)
```